How to get webViewLink of a file stored in my computer by Google Drive using PowerShell?
I would like to create a list of all files in a folder with its name and the webViewLink taken from the files sync'ed by Google Drive. I can get webViewLink for a particular file if I right click and select "Copy Link to Clipboard", I want to use PowerShell to generate this list programmatically. How do I do that?
Thanks!
The webViewLink must be an attribute of the file.
